# Errno 13 Permission denied: '/test.txt'

Tags: python

Which line should I change to fix this?

> Errno 13 Permission denied: '/test.txt'

```
def summarizer(algo):
     text = excel_preprocessor()
     if algo is 'gensimTextRank':
         text_summarized = summarize(text, word_count=5000)
         return text_summarized
     elif algo is 'sumyTextRank':
         parser = PlaintextParser(text, Tokenizer('english'))
         stemmer = Stemmer('english')
         text_summarizer = TextRankSummarizer(stemmer)
         text_summarizer.stop_words = get_stop_words('english')
         summarized = text_summarizer(parser.document, 25)
         sent = []
         for sentence in summarized:
             sent.append(str(sentence))
         text_summarized = "\n\n".join(sent)
         return text_summarized
     else:
         msg = "Accepted Inputs are: \n1. gensimTextRank\n2. sumyTextRank"
         print(msg)
          if __name__ == "__main__":
     text = summarizer('gensimTextRank')
     text = text.replace("\n", "\n\n")
     with open(r"/test.txt", "w") as f:
         f.writelines(text)
```

Comment: `with open(r"/path/with/read/write/permissions/test.txt", "w") as f: ... `

Comment: Generally, no-one but root user should be writing files to `/` path

Comment: You probably mean `"./test.txt"`.

Comment: Tip: If you are not sure what line to change, then you should read how to make a [mcve]

Comment: run `chown yourUser:yourGroup test.txt` command to the file

Answer (score -1):

run `chown yourUser:yourGroup test.txt`